# python adjusted subtotals sum to the rounded total price

Tags: python, algorithm

I have this python function question that I can't seem to wrap my head around.
Write a function that takes a list of prices, `prices`, and finds the floor or ceiling of each `price[i]` so that the adjusted subtotals sum to the rounded total price and the adjusted subtotals are also as close to the original subtotals as possible. Phrased mathematically, you should minimize **the sum of the absolute differences** of the adjusted subtotals from the original subtotals. Return the list with the adjusted subtotals. (yeah a mouthful, right)

Example input:

```
prices: [5.40, 3.30, 5.00]
```

Example output:

```
[6, 3, 5]
```

Explanation:

```
5.40 + 3.30 + 5.00 = 13.70
13.70 is rounded to 14
The way to get 14 while adjusting the prices the least is ceil(5.40) and floor(3.30).
```

the below code is as far as I got, I'm not exactly sure what's next

```
prices = [5.40,3.30, 5.00]
total_price = 0
for price in prices:
    total_price+=price

total_avg = round(total_price)
print("total_avg:",total_avg)

prices.sort()
min_price = prices[0]
max_price = prices[-1]

print("min_price:",min_price)
print("max_price:",max_price)

>>>total_avg: 14
>>>min_price: 3.3
>>>max_price: 5.4
```

Comment: It's likely you'll need to do an exhaustive search where you try every combination of floor and ceiling for every price (that's 2^n combinations).  Then discard the ones that don't add up to the correct rounded total, and among the rest find the one that has the smallest sum of absolute differences (the "l1 norm").  This sounds like a homework problem, so it's best for you to write the code.

Comment: @craigb thanks..this is not a homework problem...just an algo question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do that in O(nlog(n)) time easily. First we calculate sum of the numbers without their decimals, then we calculate the required rounded sum, we find out their difference. We then sort the values of their difference in ascending order then we get the ceil of those numbers which have higher decimal so their absolute diff is minimized and get floor of those numbers with lower decimal values. We use binary search to find out those numbers with higher decimal values.Each of those bisect calls will take log(n) time so our overall complexity is nLog(n) and the overall order of the array is still preserved.

```
import math
import bisect

prices = [5.40,3.30, 5.00]
ans = round(sum(prices))
pure_sum = sum([math.floor(i) for i in prices])
diff = ans-pure_sum
abs_diff = sorted([i-math.floor(i) for i in prices if (i%1!=0)])
for i in range(len(prices)):
    if bisect.bisect(abs_diff,prices[i]-math.floor(prices[i])) > diff:
        prices[i] = math.ceil(prices[i])
    else:
        prices[i] = math.floor(prices[i])

print(prices)
```

Comment: You missed the part in bold in the question: "minimize **the sum of the absolute differences**". For example input [3.30,5.40,5.00] gives output [4,5,5]. That has a  sum of absolute differences which is `0.70 + 0.40 + 0.00 = 1.10`. The correct answer is [3,6,5], where the sum of the absolute differences is `0.30 + 0.60 + 0.00 = 0.90`.

Comment: The correction may be as simple as finding the `k` elements with the largest fractional part, where  `k = ans - pure_sum`. Use `ceil` with those elements, and `floor` with the others.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, if we dont care about the order of the final array, we can map every value to its absolute diff using a dictionary and sort the dictionary by their absolute values, then get the ceil then the floor.

Comment: Sounds right, but I don't know if the order of the final array is important. That's something only the OP can answer. If it is important, then it's just more bookkeeping to track the original index.

Comment: We could just use binary_search and find  if its position is greated than the diff, if its indeed greater then we make it ceil or  floor otherwise :)